# Boolean indexing with Numpy Array, tuples and Ellipsis

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas, tuples

I understand Numpy array boolean indexing concept with integers

```
In [95]: a=np.array([1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2])

In [96]: a==1
Out[96]: array([ True, False, False, False,  True, False], dtype=bool

In [97]: a[a==1]
Out[97]: array([1, 1])
```

But I don't understand how comparison works with Numpy Array and tuple
and so why

```
In [106]: a = np.array([(2011, 3), (2011, 3), (2011, 3), ..., (2015, 6), (2015, 6),
   (2015, 6), (2011, 3), (2011, 3)], dtype=object)
```

(...) being an Ellipsis

returns

```
In [107]: a==(2011,3)
Out[107]: False
```

I was expecting an array like

```
array([ True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

How can I compare a Numpy Array with tuples to a tuple to get an array of boolean ?

With Pandas that's quite simple

```
In [113]: pd.Series(a)==(2011, 3)
Out[113]:
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
5    False
6    False
7     True
8     True
dtype: bool
```

But I'm looking for a pure Numpy solution.

Comment: Can you show how you constructed your array as this works for me:
`In [138]:

a = np.array([(2011, 3), (2011, 3), (2011, 3), (2015, 6), (2015, 6),
   (2015, 6), (2011, 3), (2011, 3)])
a==(2011,3)
Out[138]:
array([[ True,  True],
       [ True,  True],
       [ True,  True],
       [False, False],
       [False, False],
       [False, False],
       [ True,  True],
       [ True,  True]], dtype=bool)`

Comment: Works fine for me If I do something like: `(a == (2011, 3)).all(axis=1)`

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary `In [123]: (a == (2011, 3)).all(axis=1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-123-abedc366d478> in <module>()
----> 1 (a == (2011, 3)).all(axis=1)

AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'all'` I'm using `In [128]: np.__version__
Out[128]: '1.9.2'`

Comment: @scls What is the value of `type(a)`?

Comment: `In [129]: type(a)
Out[129]: numpy.ndarray`

Comment: @EdChum I was expecting an array like `array([ True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)`

Comment: Can you post your numpy and python version, I'm using python 3.3.4 64-bit and np 1.9.2

Comment: `$ python --version
Python 3.4.3 :: Anaconda 2.3.0 (x86_64)` and np 1.9.2 . I'm using Mac OS X 10.10

Comment: @EdChum @AshwiniChaudhary problem seems to be because of `Ellipsis` (`...`)

Comment: You can see in my code snippet I deliberately did not have ellipsis as I thought your code was truncating the output so it worked fine

Comment: Sorry, not really, because I have Ellipsis !  `    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])
    df = df.set_index('Timestamp')
    df.index = df.index.tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('UTC')

    # Get Numpy arrays from DataFrame
    direction = df['direction'].values
    var = df['speed'].values
    index = df.index.values
    by = df.index.map(by_func_monthly)
(by == (2011, 3)).all(axis=1)`

Comment: Well I don't know what np's problem here with the ellipsis, it's very strange

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86967/discussion-between-scls-and-edchum).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `a` is dtype `object`.  Many ordinary array operations are not defined for this type of array, and often it reverts to treating the array as a list.

```
In [382]: a==(2011,3)
Out[382]: False
In [383]: a.tolist()==(2011,3)
Out[383]: False
```

As @Alexander points out you could use a list comprehension to perform an element by element comparison. This version will work even with the `Ellipsis`:

```
In [399]: [i==(2011,3) for i in a]
Out[399]: [True, True, True, False, False, False, False, True, True]
```

The `Ellipsis` is not producing the scalar boolean.  I can replace it with a tuple, and still get the scalar.

```
In [384]: a1=a.copy()
In [385]: a1[3]=(0,0)
...
In [387]: a1==(2011,3)
Out[387]: False
```

The `Ellipsis` at first glance looks like a printing artifact.  But the fact that `pd.Series(a)==(2011, 3)` produces exactly 9 values suggests that it might not be - unless it is just cooincidence that `pd` formatting substitutes `Ellipsis` for only one element.

The `Ellispsis` may be the reason why `a` is object dtype.

```
In [389]: np.array([(2011, 3), (2011, 3), (2011, 3), Ellipsis, (2015, 6), (2015, 6),(2015, 6), (2011, 3), (2011, 3)])
Out[389]: 
array([(2011, 3), (2011, 3), (2011, 3), Ellipsis, (2015, 6), (2015, 6),
       (2015, 6), (2011, 3), (2011, 3)], dtype=object)
```

without it `np.array` produces a 2d array:

```
In [390]: np.array([(2011, 3), (2011, 3), (2011, 3), (2015, 6), (2015, 6),(2015, 6), (2011, 3), (2011, 3)])
Out[390]: 
array([[2011,    3],
       [2011,    3],
       [2011,    3],
       [2015,    6],
       [2015,    6],
       [2015,    6],
       [2011,    3],
       [2011,    3]])
```

`a1` without the ellipsis could be converted to 2d with:

```
In [396]: a1.astype('i,i').view(int).reshape(-1,2)
Out[396]: 
array([[2011,    3],
       [2011,    3],
       [2011,    3],
       [   0,    0],
       [2015,    6],
       [2015,    6],
       [2015,    6],
       [2011,    3],
       [2011,    3]])
```

The 2d can be tested with `(...).all(axis=1)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
a = np.array([(2011, 3), (2011, 3), (2011, 3), (2015, 6), (2015, 6), (2015, 6), (2011, 3), (2011, 3)], dtype=object)

>>> [(x, y) == (2011, 3) for x, y in a]
[True, True, True, False, False, False, True, True]
```